# How to parse JSON records in Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm working on a spark structured streaming app and I'm trying to parse JSON given in below format.

```
{"name":"xyz","age":29,"details":["city":"mumbai","country":"India"]}
{"name":"abc","age":25,"details":["city":"mumbai","country":"India"]}
```

Below is my Spark code to parse the JSON:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import spark.implicits._
 val schema= new StructType()
    .add("name",DataTypes.StringType )
    .add("age", DataTypes.IntegerType)
    .add("details",
      new StructType()
        .add("city", DataTypes.StringType)
        .add("country", DataTypes.StringType)
    )

  val dfLogLines = dfRawData.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") //Converting binary to text

  val personNestedDf = dfLogLines.select(from_json($"value", schema).as("person"))
  val personFlattenedDf = personNestedDf.selectExpr("person.name", "person.age")

  personFlattenedDf.printSchema()
  personFlattenedDf.writeStream.format("console").option("checkpointLocation",checkpoint_loc3).start().awaitTermination()
```

Output:

```
root
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- age: integer (nullable = true)

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+----+----+
|name| age|
+----+----+
|null|null|
|null|null|
+----+----+
```

The code does not throw any error but it returns null values in output. What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** The JSON looks not well-formed in the `details` field.

---

From the documentation of [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) standard function:

> Returns null, in the case of an unparseable string.

The issue is with the `details` field.

> {"details":["city":"mumbai","country":"India"]}

It looks like an array or a map, but none matches.

```
scala> Seq(Array("one", "two")).toDF("value").toJSON.show(truncate = false)
+-----------------------+
|value                  |
+-----------------------+
|{"value":["one","two"]}|
+-----------------------+

scala> Seq(Map("one" -> "two")).toDF("value").toJSON.show(truncate = false)
+-----------------------+
|value                  |
+-----------------------+
|{"value":{"one":"two"}}|
+-----------------------+

scala> Seq(("mumbai", "India")).toDF("city", "country").select(struct("city", "country") as "details").toJSON.show(truncate = false)
+-----------------------------------------------+
|value                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|{"details":{"city":"mumbai","country":"India"}}|
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

My recommendation would be to do the JSON parsing yourself using a user-defined function (UDF).

Comment: Thanks! The JSON was not well formed.